# How to make an image in a bitmap fit to screen size in Xamarin

Tags: xml, xamarin, bitmap, splash-screen

I'm currently modifying a splash screen into my App. The method I used to add it came from this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

What I want to do is make it so that the splash screen image scales to fit in the screen, as it is going to be used on different devices.

Here is my code as of yet (this is an .xml file called `splash_screen.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/tor34small2"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />"</item>
</layer-list>
```

I am close; `android:gravity="fill_horizontal` does make the image fit to the screen, well, horizontally, but I'm wondering if I can write it differently here to make it fit on both X and Y. I have tried setting it to be `android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"` as [per this guide](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8373/followed-splash-screen-guide-but-image-is-stretched-not-centered), but to no avail. Can I achieve what I want in bitmap alone, or do I have to do some additional coding outside of this .xml file?

Comment: How about set android:scaleType="fitXY"? And also read [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/112803/what-is-the-best-resoulution-for-splash-screen-in-android) may help.